# StripeException: No Such Plan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I'm creating a customer object and assigning them to a plan in Stripe and am getting the error "no such plan exists." The plan id that's given in the error is the correct plan id: `No such plan: prod_EIcYiWkVa7LF7T`

It may be worth noting that the customer's StripeCustomerId also isn't being written to the database, but that may be because the code is failing later on so no changes are made.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscribeViewModel model)
        {

            string CurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var CurrentUser = UserManager.FindById(CurrentUserId);


            StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"]);

            var custoptions = new CustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Description = "Customer object for " + CurrentUser.Email,
                SourceToken = model.StripeToken
            };

            var custservice = new CustomerService();
            Customer customer = custservice.Create(custoptions);

            CurrentUser.StripeCustomerId = customer.Id;

            var items = new List<SubscriptionItemOption>
            {
                new SubscriptionItemOption
                {
                    PlanId = db.Plans.Where(a=>a.Id == CurrentUser.Plan).FirstOrDefault().StripePlanId
                }
            };
            var options = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
            {
                CustomerId = CurrentUser.StripeCustomerId,
                Items = items
            };

            var service = new SubscriptionService();
            Subscription subscription = service.Create(options);


            CurrentUser.PlanStatus = "TRIAL";
            CurrentUser.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(model.Plan.TrialDays);
            var Plan = db.Plans.Where(a => a.Id == CurrentUser.Plan).FirstOrDefault();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: `prod_EIcYiWkVa7LF7T` is a Product Id. You want a `plan_xxx` ID of a pricing plan for that product. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/products-and-plans

Comment: Ah, perfect. That fixed it. Do you have any idea why, based on the above code, the StripeCustomerId wouldn't be written to the database? Does it have to do with the timing of the API calls?

Comment: Do you save or do anything with the `CurrentUser` object? It doesn't seems to be a clear `save` function called on it anywhere (although I'm not ASP programmer, but expected to see something like that in the code)

Comment: Just wanted to add, that this error message also occurs when your `publishable`/`secret` keys are wrong. Stripe's error messages really are not helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This was posted above as a comment, but I'm adding it as an answer with apologies to @karllekko, since I almost passed by it without reading it.

You want to use the Plan ID, `plan_xxxxx`, not the Product ID, `prod_xxxxx`. I made the same mistake of creating multiple products instead of one product with multiple price plans.

Create a single product, then set up multiple plans per product for your "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze" etc. pricing and use those `plan_xxxxx` IDs in your code to create subscriptions.

Comment: I'll add that there is nomenclature conflict  between `price` and `plan`.  think 'price_plan'.  The dashboard does not lead one into creating a product's price/plan.  So the product is not what is being sold, but the product_price is.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the price API Id instead of using prod_ID above.

As the picture shows, it worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Enable Client Integration

I was stuck on this, tried the previous answers and nothing seemed to work, it happens that [you must enable Client Integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client#enable-checkout), it's disabled for any new account by default. You can do it on the [Checkout & Payment Links](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout)

Beware it has its warnings. It's better to integrate on backend.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Check that the API key is correct**

Make sure to sign in with your account when viewing the Documentation and have a look at the demo code and verify that the API key is correct. I was working on 2 branches and didn't notice that each branch had different API keys.