# error when charged { Error: No such plan: on stripe with Node JS

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to make a monthly billing plan using node JS with stripe.

I get this error:

```
error when charged { Error: No such plan:
```

Here is my code:

```
const keyPublishable = "pk_test_DbEg2qVxduEZaIOl03AJAKX800fGtReb3c";
const keySecret = "XXX";
app.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
try {
    var customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken
    })

    await stripe.subscriptions.create({ // no point in awaiting here
        plan: 'prod_EjuGPEbcrhczeA',
        customer: customer.id
    })
    res.render("charge.pug")
```

In the logs of stripe I get :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such plan: prod_EjuGPEbcrhczeA",
    "param": "plan",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: From [this question's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079124/stripeexception-no-such-plan) : "[`prod_EjuGPEbcrhczeA`] is a Product Id. You want a `plan_xxx` ID of a pricing plan for that product (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/products-and-plans)"

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Like you said Was using the wrong ID.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the id you are using is wrong. It's product id not plan id. What you need is to create a plan using the API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create.

Then use id of newly created plan to create subscription.

Comment: Thank you, Like you and Seblor said, I was using the wrong plan.